# Why is this html not updating using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

I have a standard jQuery ajax function:

```
$.ajax({ 

    // blah blah...

    success: function(data) 
    {
        if(data) 
        {
            $('.title').text(data.title);
            $('.description').text(data.description);
            if (data.image) 
            {
                $('div#image').html('<a href="'+data.image+'" class="button">View Image</a>');                      
            }
        }
    }

});
```

The server response is a json object. `data.image` returns a url of the image location. I am simply sticking it in a link and sticking that inside a div.

This ajax call runs every time the user clicks a "next" or "prev" button on a gallery. The problem is, after the first time that link is loaded, it stays cached or something because even when I click next or prev and everything else updates like title and description, that link won't update. It always points to the first image.

The really weird thing is, if I replace this:

```
$('div#image').html('<a href="'+data.image+'" class="button">View Image</a>');
```

with:

```
$('div#image').html(data.image);
```

it works fine, a new url is loaded each time the ajax call runs. But if I put that inside some html, then it loads once and stays cached or something.

Does anyone know why this may be happening?

Comment: I doubt this is your problem, but you shouldn't just concatenate `data.image` into your HTML string. Think about what happens if `data.image` would contain a quote or any other character that has special meaning in HTML. Instead, you may want to set the HTML without the `href`, then find the `a` element created and use `attr` to set the `href`.

Comment: Are you attaching an event listener to `#image a`?

Answer (score 2):

Tom, there isn't enough information here to really determine what's wrong but if simply referencing data.image by itself works fine, why not reword your function to use it that way.

```
$.ajax({ 
    // blah blah...
    success: function(data) 
    {
        if(data) 
        {
            $('.title').text(data.title);
            $('.description').text(data.description);
            if (data.image) 
            {
                $('div#image a').attr('href',data.image);                      
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

Try putting that somewhere in your script before the call

Or in your $.ajax call put a parameter

```
cache: true
```